# Array of custom Object in PHP like Java

Tags: java, php

In Java,

I can create something like the following:

```
public class A {
    private final SomeCustomClass[] nodes;

    public A() {
        //create new SomeCustomClass
        node1 = new SomeCustomClass(100, 200);

        //create the more SomeCustomClass as array
        nodes = new SomeCustomClass[100]; //this is a array of type "SomeCustomClass"

        //fill these nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            nodes[i] = new SomeCustomClass(1, 5);
        }

    }
}
```

Would the following suffice as its PHP implementation? I'm confused about the Java's `nodes = new SomeCustomClass[100]` part.

```
class A {

    private $node1;
    private $nodes;

    public function __construct() {
        //create new SomeCustomClass
        $this->node1 = new SomeCustomClass(100, 200);

        //create the more SomeCustomClass as array
        $this->nodes = new ArrayObject();

        //fill these SomeCustomClass
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
            $this->nodes[$i] = new SomeCustomClass(1, 5);
        }

    }
}
```

I have `SomeCustomClass` which is my own defined class.

Comment: where you are getting  problem  ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: Hello, my `$this->nodes` is not adding anything. Would you like to switch to chat (I don't have enough reputation to start a chat)?

Comment: Check my answer and update me new status.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, may be tere are better way, but now, I only can think about this.

```
class Customer 
{
    var $item;

    function __construct($arg){
        $this->item = $arg;
        $customer[] = $this->item;
    }
}

$customer = new Customer(1234);
var_dump($customer);
    ?>
```

Output

> object(Customer)[1]   public 'item' => int 1234

another is implementation of collection may be like

```
class Collection 
{
    private $items = array();

    public function addItem($obj, $key = null) {
        if ($key == null) {
            $this->items[] = $obj;
        }
        else {
            if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
                throw new KeyHasUseException("Key $key already in use.");
            }
            else {
                $this->items[$key] = $obj;
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteItem($key) {
        if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
            unset($this->items[$key]);
        }
        else {
            throw new KeyInvalidException("Invalid key $key.");
        }
    }

    public function getItem($key) {
        if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
            return $this->items[$key];
        }
        else {
            throw new KeyInvalidException("Invalid key $key.");
        }
    }
}
class Salut
{
    private $name;
    private $number;

    public function __construct($name, $number) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->number = $number;
    }
}
$c = new Collection();
$c->addItem(new Salut("Steve", 14), "steve");
$c->addItem(new Salut("Ed", 37), "ed");
$c->addItem(new Salut("Bob", 49), "bob");
try {
    $c->getItem("steve");
}
catch (KeyInvalidException $e) {
    print "The collection doesn't contain Steve.";
}
var_dump($c);
```

Output

> object(Collection)[1]   private 'items' => 
>       array (size=3)
>         'steve' => 
>           object(Salut)[2]
>             private 'name' => string 'Steve' (length=5)
>             private 'number' => int 14
>         'ed' => 
>           object(Salut)[3]
>             private 'name' => string 'Ed' (length=2)
>             private 'number' => int 37
>         'bob' => 
>           object(Salut)[4]
>             private 'name' => string 'Bob' (length=3)
>             private 'number' => int 49

Answer (score 0):

Usually in PHP you would create an array like:

```
$this->nodes = array();
```

The rest of your code is fine though you can also add to the end of an array using:

```
$this->nodes[] = new SomeCustomClass(1, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your problem. You must not think Java way when programming in PHP as they are different on the type system.

While Java is [statically typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking), PHP is [dynamically typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type_checking_and_runtime_type_information). They are two different worlds.

While in Java the type of a variable is checked at compile time, everything in PHP is checked at runtime (exceptionally when you use PHP type checking).

Plus, the array data structure in Java is way different to the array PHP data structure.

In java the array is homogeneous, i.e when you type

`int a = new int[10]`

All values of this array must be of the type of `int`.

However in PHP the array (which is an hash like structure that can act as several data structures in one) is heterogeneous. This means that can contains every type.

`$array = [1, "a", new stdClass(), []];`

Think it as a Java array of `Object`. So your implementation is semantically correct. (I would have used the native array)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question while looking for a solution, if anyone needs help look into:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Or create your own methods to validate the object type before adding.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30970862)